# Proving correctness for code computing function.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computability, computer-arithmetic

I was solving an exercise from the book "Complexity, computability and languages" which asks:

> Write a program that computes $f(x)=1 \iff x$ is even, $f(x)=0\iff x$ is odd.

I wrote the following code, which I believe is correct:

$$
Z\leftarrow Z +1 \\
\quad\quad\text{IF X $\neq$ 0 GOTO A}\\
[C]Y \leftarrow Y+1\\
\quad\quad\text{IF Z $\neq$ 0 GOTO E}\\
[A] X\leftarrow X-1\\
\quad\quad\text{IF X$\neq$ 0 GOTO B}\\
\quad\quad\text{IF Z$\neq$0 GOTO E }\\
[B] X\leftarrow X-1\\
\quad\quad\text{IF X$\neq$ 0 GOTO A}\\
\quad\quad\text{IF Z$\neq$ 0 GOTO C}\\
$$
$X$ is the input variable. $Y$ is the output variable and $Z$ is an temporary variable. The latter 2 are initialized at $0$.

And I want to prove this code correctly computes $f$ (not part of the exercise), how hard is this?

Comment: Where is label $E$? If that means go to the end then this program is incorrect because if $X$ is $2$ then you will jump to the end and since $Y$ has not been initialized you will output $0$. Therefore, you will have computed $f(2)=0$.

Comment: Yes, doing a go to to a label that doesn't appear in the program is the same as quitting. That was a typo, the first goto should've been to $A$, I'll edit that. Thanks!

Comment: You could start by indicating what variables contain the input and output, and possibly how are Y and Z initialised (assuming X is initialised to the input?

Comment: @ConradTurner Sure, just editted.